# How to build a customized 3D Object modeling with Aspose 3D lib

Tags: c#, aspose

I'm trying to build a 3D object model. But my code just has rendered a 3D model with a specific colour in the image.

How can I create a 3D object with 6 images for each surface like a Rubik cube?

This is my code, using Aspose 3D lib and C#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create a FBX file with embedded textures
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.Open("BetterShirt.obj");
    //Create an embedded texture
    Texture tex = new Texture()
    {
        Content = CreateTextureContent(),
        FileName = "face.png",
        WrapModeU = Aspose.ThreeD.Shading.WrapMode.Wrap,
    };

    tex.SetProperty("TexProp", "value");
    //create a material with custom property
    //Aspose.ThreeD.Shading.
    Material mat = scene.RootNode.ChildNodes[0].Material;
    mat.SetTexture(Material.MapDiffuse, tex);
    mat.SetProperty("MyProp", 1.0);

    scene.RootNode.ChildNodes[0].Material = mat;
    //save this to file
    scene.Save("exported.obj", FileFormat.WavefrontOBJ);
}

private static byte[] CreateTextureContent()
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, 128, 128),
                Color.Moccasin, Color.Blue, 45);
            using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 40))
            {
                g.DrawString("Aspose.3D", font, brush, Point.Empty);
            }
        }
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

build an 3D object model with 6 images

Answer (score 0):

We have devised below code based on your requirements. Comments have also been added for your reference. Please try using it in your environment and then share your kind feedback with us.

```
    private static void RubikCube()
    {
        Bitmap[] bitmaps = CreateRubikBitmaps();
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        //create a box and convert it to mesh, so we can manually specify the material per face
        var box = (new Box()).ToMesh();

        //create a material mapping, the box mesh generated from Box primitive class contains 6 polygons, then we can reference the material of polygon(specified by MappingMode.Polygon) by index(ReferenceMode.Index)
        var materials = (VertexElementMaterial)box.CreateElement(VertexElementType.Material, MappingMode.Polygon, ReferenceMode.Index);
        //and each polygon uses different materials, the indices of these materials are specified below
        materials.SetIndices(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        //create the node and materials(referenced above)
        var boxNode = scene.RootNode.CreateChildNode(box);
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.Length; i++)
        {
            //create material with texture
            var material = new LambertMaterial();
            var tex = new Texture();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmaps[i].Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                //Save it to Texture.Content as embedded texture, thus the scene with textures can be exported into a single FBX file.
                tex.Content = bytes;
                //Give it a name and save it to disk so it can be opened with .obj file 
                tex.FileName = string.Format("cube_{0}.png", i);
                File.WriteAllBytes(tex.FileName, bytes);
                //Dispose the bitmap since we're no longer need it.
                bitmaps[i].Dispose();
            }
            //the texture is used as diffuse
            material.SetTexture(Material.MapDiffuse, tex);
            //attach it to the node where contains the box mesh
            boxNode.Materials.Add(material);
        }
        //save it to file

        //3D viewer of Windows 10 does not support multiple materials, you'll see same textures in each face, but the tools from Autodesk does
        scene.Save("test.fbx", FileFormat.FBX7500ASCII);
        //NOTE: Multiple materials of mesh in Aspose.3D's OBJ Exporter is not supported yet.
        //But we can split the mesh with multiple materials into different meshes by using PolygonModifier.SplitMesh
        PolygonModifier.SplitMesh(scene, SplitMeshPolicy.CloneData);
        //following code will also generate a material library file(test.mtl) which uses the textures exported in above code.
        scene.Save("test.obj", FileFormat.WavefrontOBJ);
    }

    private static Bitmap[] CreateRubikBitmaps()
    {
        Brush[] colors = { Brushes.White, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Orange, Brushes.Green};
        Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[6];
        //initialize the cell colors
        int[] cells = new int[6 * 9];
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
        {
            cells[i] = i / 9;
        }
        //shuffle the cells
        Random random = new Random();
        Array.Sort(cells, (a, b) => random.Next(-1, 2));
        //paint each face

        // size of each face is 256px
        const int size = 256;
        // size of cell is 80x80 
        const int cellSize = 80;
        // calculate padding size between each cell
        const int paddingSize = (size - cellSize * 3) / 4;
        int cellId = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            bitmaps[i] = new Bitmap(size, size, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmaps[i]))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Black);
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    //calculate the cell's position
                    int row = j / 3;
                    int column = j % 3;
                    int y = row * (cellSize + paddingSize) + paddingSize;
                    int x = column * (cellSize + paddingSize) + paddingSize;
                    Brush cellBrush = colors[cells[cellId++]];
                    //paint cell
                    g.FillRectangle(cellBrush, x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
        }
        return bitmaps;
    }
```

**PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.